# How to initialize multiple constants that depend on the same condition

Tags: javascript

I need to initialize three constants in order to calculate something. However, the values of these three constants all depend on the same boolean property which is why I currently initialize them as follows:

```js
let startIndex = 0;
let endIndex   = this.count;
let increment  = 1;
if(this.revert) {
  startIndex = this.count;
  endIndex   = 0;
  increment  = -1;
}
```

The obvious downside here is that I'm now dealing with variables, not constants. Therefore I'm not protected from accidentally overriding their values.

I could initialize them as follows to prevent that disadvantage:

```js
const startIndex = this.revert ? this.count : 0;
const endIndex   = this.revert ? 0 : this.count;
const increment  = this.revert ? -1 : 1;
```

Now the values are actual constants but for each initialization the condition must be checked independently which likely requires more processing time than the first approach.

Sure, answers to this might be opinion-based and I'm aware that I'm splitting hairs here but I'm interested in objective answers why one approach is preferable over the other, if this is actually the case.

Good code is made up of a myriad of small decisions and this is one such decision so I feel that my question is justified.

Comment: cycles are wasted both ways: in the first snippet, you re-assign three times, in the second you check three times. However, this is a quite negligible amount of cycles. Choose the one that looks the  best, IMO the second.

Comment: I can just assume the context of this code, but if it's not in a hot path, then it doesn't really have any impact on overall performance, so you shouldn't worry about that. I would go with the second one, because it's more readable.

Answer (score 0):

You can define variable and set conditionally and finally assign to your constant:

```
let startIndex = 0;
let endIndex   = this.count;
let increment  = 1;
if(this.revert) {
  startIndex = this.count;
  endIndex   = 0;
  increment  = -1;
}

const StartIndex = startIndex;
const EndIndex = endIndex;
const Increment = incremen;
```